# Найти цифру в строке и вывести строку после числа [JS]

Tags: javascript, node.js, строки

Мне нужно сделать функцию с аргументом для поиска числа в строке и вывести строку после этого числа

Пример:

найти цифру "2"
'111111123333ab' => '23333ab'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function getFromSubstr( str, substr ){ // type string | undefined
  let index = str.indexOf(substr);
  if( index < 0 ) return;
  return str.substr(index);
}

console.log( getFromSubstr( '111111123333ab', '2' ) );
```

Comment: Наверное, нужно вставить проверку на неотрицательность индекса, не то будут неожиданные результаты (символ с конца), если символ не будет найден.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty да, спасибо, поправил